# How to setup multiple simultaneous access to x11vnc session

Tags: xorg, vnc

I have setup an x11vnc server on a computer and I am able to access it with no issues via remote desktop clients. But I am only able to access it, one at a time (i.e. on my laptop but not on both my laptop and on my tablet at the same time).

Is there a switch I need to pass when I start the vncserver for this or is it just a limitation of x11vnc that I missed?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From `man x11vnc`

```
   -shared

          VNC  display is shared, i.e. more than one viewer can connect at
          the same time (default off).

   -once

          Exit after the first successfully connected viewer  disconnects,
          opposite of -forever. This is the Default.

   -forever

          Keep  listening for more connections rather than exiting as soon
          as the first client(s) disconnect. Same as -many
```

So you probably want `-shared -forever`

Comment: actual behaviour of the default 'once' is; exit after viewercount reaches 0 after having been positive before. So if 2 connect and then 1 disconnects, it remains active, and the disconnected viewer can reconnect again.